# TFS Build failing because of Code Analysis settings

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, msbuild, code-analysis

I've turned on Code Analysis for all of my projects, and have verified code analysis is on for each configuration (Debug, Release, QA, etc). My local builds are of course fine, my TFS builds are failing still.

Here is the failed output XML file in the drop location for my builds:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Tests xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <BuildConfigurationSettings name="Debug" ProjectName="MyProject" Platform="AnyCPU">
    <Test>
      <MSBuildSchemaName>CodeAnalysisRuleSet</MSBuildSchemaName>
      <ExpectedValue>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</ExpectedValue>
      <ActualValue />
      <Verify>true</Verify>
      <TestExecuted>true</TestExecuted>
      <IsEqual>false</IsEqual>
    </Test>
  </BuildConfigurationSettings>
  <BuildConfigurationSettings name="Release" ProjectName="MyProject" Platform="AnyCPU">
    <Test>
      <MSBuildSchemaName>CodeAnalysisRuleSet</MSBuildSchemaName>
      <ExpectedValue>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</ExpectedValue>
      <ActualValue />
      <Verify>true</Verify>
      <TestExecuted>true</TestExecuted>
      <IsEqual>false</IsEqual>
    </Test>
  </BuildConfigurationSettings>
</Tests>
```

Comment: Have you specified path to the code analysis tools or just enabled code analysis?

Comment: Is the version of FXCop that you are running locally the same as the version on your build machine?

Comment: @PabloC -not sure. I don't have the rights to the build machine

Comment: @sll -I've looked at some other projects under TFS that are known to have built correctly. I've verified that their 'path' to the code analysis tools is the same as mine. So shouldn't be a problem there...

Comment: @ErOx : try out setting it explicitly as shown below

Comment: Consider setting you build verbosity into `Diagnostic` & provide  with this output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, even though Code Analysis was turned on in the 'Properties' for the failing projects, the changes were not being reflected in the .csproj file. After hand-editing the .csproj file to include the minimum ruleset, everything was working fine:

```
<CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio edition on build server should support for code analysis And there are some [known issues:](http://seesharper.wordpress.com/2010/04/02/code-analysis-in-team-build-2010/)

> Unfortunately due to a bug discovered very late in the release cycle
> the install for Code Analysis does not execute on x64 build servers.
> This means you won’t see code analysis running despite correct
> configuration. The work around for now is to install a Visual Studio
> SKU that includes Code Analysis on the build machine to get the FxCop
> installation.